# SQL Subquery - Inexperienced!

Tags: sql, sorting, subquery

I have a database, and I'm trying to show the count of users for each different entry in the "source" field. So for example, show how many people share the same source. Would I have to do this through a subquery? Or do I have to actually know what the titles of the sources are in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), source FROM mytable GROUP BY source;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'd use grouping:

```
select source, count(*) from users group by source ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Source, count(Source) as TotalPeople
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Source
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `GROUP BY` query.

Start here: http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

This counts the record grouped by the values of myField:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) As rCount FROM myTable GROUP BY myField
```

You can also group your query with multiple GROUP clauses.
This will give you the counting of any sub-grouping:

```
SELECT myField1, myField2, COUNT(1) As rCount FROM myTable GROUP BY myField1, myField2
```

The `COUNT(1)` is better than `COUNT(*)`, for the Sql engine.